# Replace gui login on gnome with cli

Tags: gnome, gdm

Is it possible to replace/disable the gui/gdm login on gnome with the cli, and after login the gnome desktop to show up?

Comment: Offtopic here. Should be moved to superuser.

Answer (score 0):

It could be distribution or configuration specific. I assume you are on Linux.

You might disable (or uninstall) the display manager, e.g. `gdm` or `lightdm`

You'll then login to the command line, and use `startx` to start the desktop.